# How to trigger button on html file when else statement condition is met on .js file

Tags: javascript, html, triggers

I have had a play around with this code which essentially automatically presses the reset button in the html file when the word is guessed correctly, but I cannot get it to work, the id of the button is reset. It is a guessing game, I want it to reset automatically when the word is guessed. The two $ scripts are my attempt at getting this to work

````
get statusMessage() {
if (this.status === 'playing'){
return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}"`
    return `Guesses left: ${this.remainingGuesses}`
} else if (this.status === 'failed') {   
streak.innerHTML = 0
    return `Nice try! The word was "${this.word.join('')}"```

} else { 
streak.innerHTML ++
return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
$('#reset').trigger('click');
$('#reset').click();
}

}
````

Answer (score 0):

$('#reset').click(); will work if you write it before return statement like this:

```
 else { 
    streak.innerHTML ++
    $('#reset').click();
    return 'Great work! You guessed the word!'
 }
```

Comment: Amazing Thank you so much